# Manually connect to MySQL with Symfony, no DBAL or ORM

Tags: mysql, symfony

How do you connect Symfony to MySQL without using any ORM? 
I'm on localhost and testing some stuff and can't figure this one out.
I just want the controller action to manually connect to database, run a query like "select * from someTable".
I don't have time to set up an Doctrine/Propel.

Is this possible? Any examples? Thanks.

EDIT:

Any examples of the PDO approach?

Further Edit:

This works:

```
$link = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('databaseName', $link);
mysql_set_charset('UTF-8', $link);

$result = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES", $link);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo var_dump($row);
}
```

Comment: It is honestly less time to do the doctrine way, but you can use PDO

Comment: Please at least use mysqli instead of mysql functions at the very least.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a Console Command might be want. It might not be too difficult.
Here's the info:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/console.html